# Web-scraping Historical Bitcoin Data from coinmarketcap.com

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am having some issues web scraping some data with beautiful soup and I am wondering if any of you scraper pros could give me some guidance.

This is the exact web page I would like to scrape:
https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?start=20130428&end=20171013

Specifically, I'd like to grab the table of historical prices and somehow extract the information into a DataFrame. But first I need to actually find it within the raw html.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?start=20130428&end=20171013') 

soup = BeautifulSoup(data._content, 'html.parser')
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting an encoding error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa0' in position 22075: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there a way to basically just strip out all of the characters that can't be encoded before passing the raw html to beautiful soup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup(data._content.decode('utf-8'))`

Try decoding `utf-8` first.

If you still have problems, you can tell the decoder to ignore errors:

`BeautifulSoup(data._content.decode('utf-8', 'ignore))`

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer your question - I am not sure how to set lxml as the parser but I successfully found and extracted the data - note there is a way to use LXML within BS but I am directly using LXML rather than accessing it through BS

```
from lxml import html
import requests


data = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?start=20130428&end=20171013').content
tree = html.fromstring(data)
# note I did not want to sort out the logic to find the table so I cheated
# and selected the table with a specific data value
mytable = tree.xpath('//td[contains(.,"4829.58")]/ancestor::table')[0]
for e in mytable.iter(tag='tr'):
    e.text_content()

    '\n                        Date\n                        Open\n                        High\n                        Low\n                        Close\n                        Volume\n                        Market Cap\n                    '
   '\n                        Oct 12, 2017\n                        4829.58\n                        5446.91\n                        4822.00\n                        5446.91\n                        2,791,610,000\n                        80,256,700,000\n                        '
```

I think the unicode problem is further up the tree (some element other than the table you arer looking for) and so I had no problem getting the data from the table or writing the result to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that worked for me (this example works in Python 3):

```py
# use urllib to get HTML data
url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/historical/20201206/"
contents = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
bytes_str = contents.read()

# decode bytes string
data_str = bytes_str.decode("utf-8")

# crop the raw JSON string out of the website HTML
start_str = '"listingHistorical":{"data":'
start = data_str.find(start_str)+len(start_str)
end = data_str.find(',"page":1,"sort":""')
cropped_str = data_str[start:end]

# create a Python list from JSON string
data_list = json.loads(cropped_str)
print ("total cryptos:", len(data_list))

# iterate over the list of crypto dicts
for i, item in enumerate(data_list):

    # pretty print all cryptos with a high rank
    if item["cmc_rank"] < 30:
        print (json.dumps(item, indent=4))
```

To get another data from another date just replace the `20201206` part in the URL with a preferred date (e.g. use `20210110` instead for Jan 10th, 2021).